# Doctrine mapping issue - Call to a member function setValue() on null

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a weird issue with Doctrine. I have set up the following structure:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fp_credit_returned_product")
 */
class ReturnedProduct {
...
    /**
     * @var FpCredit\Models\Credit\ReturnedProductDetail
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\FpCredit\Models\Credit\ReturnedProductDetail", mappedBy="returned_product", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $details;

public function getDetails() {
    return $this->details;
}

public function setDetails($details) {
    $this->details = $details;
}
```

and:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fp_credit_returned_product_detail")
 */
class ReturnedProductDetail {

     /**
     * @var FpCredit\Models\Credit\ReturnedProduct
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\FpCredit\Models\Credit\ReturnedProduct")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="returned_product_id", nullable=false, referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $returnedProduct;

    public function getReturnedProduct() {
        return $this->returnedProduct;
    }

    public function setReturnedProduct($returnedProduct) {
        $this->returnedProduct = $returnedProduct;
    }
```

Then I query all returnedProducts and do the following:

```
foreach ($errorLogs as $eLog) {
    $errorDetails = $eLog->getDetails();
    if ($errorDetails) {
        foreach ($errorDetails as $errorDetail) {

            $errorArticle = $errorDetail->getArticle();
        }
    }
}
```

Because of the `$errorDetail->getArticle()` I get this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function setValue() on null in /var/www/html/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php
```

Does anybody know why this error occurs and how I can fix it? Is something wrong with my mapping? One ReturnedProducts has several ReturnProductDetails.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just want to add that even though my mapping was correct the doctrine cache was out of sync with my code and causing the error. Restarting my docker containers fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you try in your class ReturnedProduct

```
mappedBy="returnedProduct"
```

regards.

Comment: and JoinColumn(name="returned_product_id" stays at it is?

Comment: it is different the name of the column, and the name of the object attribute.
The mapping occur on the attributes names

Comment: Now it works, so mappedBy needs the name of variable and not the name of the column.